# Docker container got some strange address, 03a0646cb148:8888/ can anyone explain what's this type of address is called?

Tags: linux, docker, ip

i was running a container which got two different addresses, i understand  http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=... and ::1 is referring to the localhost in ipv4 and 6 respectively  but where does this http://03a0646cb148:8888/?token=... address comes from ???

```
lib@DESKTOP-ISQPMPU:~$ docker run --rm  -p 8888:8888  -v $PWD:/home/jovyan/pwd  --env JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes  --env JUPYTER_TOKEN=x --name ihaskell_notebook crosscompass/ihaskell-notebook:latest
[sudo] password for lib:
Executing the command: jupyter lab
[I 15:35:31.698 LabApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 15:35:34.001 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 15:35:34.001 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[I 15:35:34.006 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 15:35:34.006 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:35:34.006 LabApp] http://03a0646cb148:8888/?token=...
[I 15:35:34.006 LabApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=...
[I 15:35:34.006 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Answer (score 1):

> where does this http://03a0646cb148:8888/?token=... address comes from ?

That's a container hostname. One of Linux's namespaces used by docker is UTS which is easiest thought of as the hostname. Hostnames in containers default to the short container id:

```
$ docker run -it --name test-host busybox hostname
e93c238e1aa3                  

$ docker container ls -l
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE      COMMAND      CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS    NAMES
e93c238e1aa3    busybox    "hostname"   About a minute ago  Exited (0) About a minute ago            test-host

$ docker container inspect test-host --format '{{.ID}}'
e93c238e1aa32b62b9c57df722ea3150a48322c266383f0d7c8e049ab7bd760c
```

Comment: any resources where i can read about this UTS namespace.....???

Comment: @MahfuzullahGalib there's the man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/uts_namespaces.7.html